# get default action for later usage in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an event that is fired off. I want to change the behavior of this event.

```
$('window').on('resize', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // this needs to be "deferred"
  Game.pause();
  someAsyncPromise().then(result => {
    Game.resume();
    // continue the default action here
  });
})
```

Is it possible to defer the default action of an event with javascript in this way?

Comment: Nope. You'd have to cancel the event and retrigger it somehow. Not sure that's possible in this case.

Comment: [That particular event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) doesn't do anything special, it is for anyone who wants to do something when it do fires, to hook into it and do something.

Comment: @LGSon: Very good point. There's no default to re-trigger.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, please add it to your answer as it does have a value in similar cases, though not as an answer by itself.

Comment: True, I tried to think of some case for an example with an async function

Comment: Hate to say it, but `resize` doesn't have a default, either (at least, not one you can prevent). The window gets resized regardless.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to defer the default action of an event with javascript in this way?

No, once all event handlers have returned and the event has finished being routed, the browser handles triggering the default action unless it's been prevented. You can't suspend the event (other than running synchronous code in a handler, of course), or reissue the default action.

It's tempting to try to fire the event again when you want the default to happen, but that's problematic even in the cases where it's possible (retriggers event handlers, many events can only be initiated by the user, etc.), and I don't think it's possible in this case anyway.

---

Side note: As [LGSon pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294815/get-default-action-for-later-usage-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment56331336_34294815), [that particular event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) doesn't have any default action, so there's no need to worry about preventing it, and no need to try to re-start it later. But the question still applies in the general case.